# If Condition in datatable data column

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm trying to add a condition to change what the column displays based on what the data is. So "Status" is "True" or "False". If it's true I want to display "Active" and if it's "False" I want to display "Inactive"

```
"aTargets": [2],
"bSortable": false,
"sType": 'numeric',
"sClass": "AutoDashGridStyle",
"sTitle": "Status",
"sWidth": "60px",
"mData": "Status",
"render": function (mData, type, row) {
     return "mData" == 'True' ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'
}
```

Should display Active or Inactive

Comment: Your `mData` is variable and you are using it as a string. If the `mData` has a boolean value you can use `mData ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'`

Comment: I should have removed my render function since it doesn't work. So I tried what you said and it didn't work. I don't think mData as a variable is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I was able to answer my own question. I simply changed the mData from

```
"mData": "Status",
```

to

```
"mData": function (source) {
return source.Status == "True" ? "Active" : "Inactive";
}
```

Comment: And that worked exactly because you **didn't** enclose function arguments into double quotes. If you'd follow suggestion from the very first comment to your initial post, that could have saved you time and effort